# Replace function in ACCESS

Tags: ms-access

I'm a beginner in MS ACCESS.
I need to join two tables: table_A and table_B. Since I want to use Replace function, but it doesn't work. My stupid code is:

```
UPDATE table_A
INNER JOIN table_B
SET table_A.name = table_B.name
ON table_A.age = Replace(table_B.age, "years-old","")
```

What's wrong with this?

Comment: Define `doesn't work`.  Do you get an error, or is `REPLACE` not working as expected?

Answer (score 3):

You must fully define the data source(s) before the `SET` clause.  So move the `ON` condition up one line:

```
UPDATE table_A
INNER JOIN table_B
ON table_A.age = Replace(table_B.age, "years-old","")
SET table_A.name = table_B.name
```

However that `ON` expression could be tricky.  The Access query designer doesn't cooperate well with `ON` expressions which include functions.  But the query could work if both `table_A.age` and `table_B.age` are text data type.

I suggest you first work this out as a `SELECT` query.  Once you have the join set up and working, you can transform it from a `SELECT` to an `UPDATE`.